# Google Spreadsheet: Change Cell value based on Data Validation selection

Tags: function, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I have this situation. 
I've created 2 different Sheet: **Sheet1** and **Sheet2**.
Inside **Sheet1** I've created a list of different text values, from A1 to A10. Each text must correspond to a numerical value that I've added on the same sheet on column B1 to B10.
Exemple A1=Home and B1=50.

On a different Sheet called **Sheet2** I've insert a Data Validation menu containing the **Sheet1** values from A1 to A10 but on multiple cells. So the Data Validation can be found on **Sheet2** from A1 to A5.

What I want to achieve is that on **Sheet2** inside the Cell B2 I have the SUM of the Data Validation selection (from A1 to A5 on **Sheet2**).
So for example:
On **Sheet1** A1=Home and B1=50.
On **Sheet2** A1:A5=Home B2 must be 250.

How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. Copy this function to the script bound to your Spreadsheet and run it:

```js
function sumValidation() {
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var data = sheet1.getRange('A1:B10').getValues();
  var resultRange = sheet2.getRange('B2');
  var result = 0;
  var validations = sheet2.getRange('A1:A5').getValues();
  for(var i = 0; i < validations.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
      if(validations[i][0] == data[j][0]) {
        result += data[j][1];
      }
    }
  }
  resultRange.setValue(result);
}
```

If you want your SUM to get updated each time you edit a value in data validation, make it an [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger.